# User inside a dockerfile doesn't have the rights to write the file he created

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am currently trying to execute a python script on a docker file.The python script creates some files, and I want to export it outside the container. It worked perfectly fine. The python script looks this way :

```py
    import os
    absolutePath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
    parentDirectory = os.path.dirname(absolutePath)

    def copyHtml(origin_path,copy_path):
        with open(origin_path,'r') as fr:
            lines = fr.readlines()
        with open(copy_path,'w') as fw:
            for line in lines:
                fw.write(line)

    def createFile(repo_path):
        if not os.path.exists(repo_path):
            os.makedirs(repo_path)

    def mirror(origin_repo,copy_repo):
        for filename in os.listdir(origin_repo):
            copy_path = os.path.join(copy_repo,filename)
            origin_path = os.path.join(origin_repo,filename)
            if os.path.isfile(origin_path):
                root,extension = os.path.splitext(origin_path)
                if extension == '.html':
                    copyHtml(origin_path,copy_path)
            else:
                createFile(copy_path)
                mirror(origin_path,copy_path)

    createFile(parentDirectory + '/electhon2')
    mirror(parentDirectory + '/electhon1',parentDirectory + '/electhon2')
```

Where electhon1 is an Html file existing on the folder where the script and the dockerfile are stored.
The dockerfile looks like this :

```
FROM python:3.10.4
RUN useradd -u 8877 nonroot
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app 
EXPOSE 5000
CMD python3 monscript.py
```

I built and image of it using `docker build -t my_image .`, and then ran it with `docker run -v /home/axel.garreau/stored_files:/app/electhon2 my_image`. So far so good.

But I encountered some permissions issues with the files copied on my computer (i.e only root could access unless using chmod or chown), so I decided not to run the dockerfile as root. I added the following lines:

```
FROM python:3.10.4
RUN useradd -u 8877 nonroot
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN chown nonroot /app
USER nonroot 
EXPOSE 5000
CMD python3 monscript.py
```

When I do, I have far stranger issues: when nonroot creates a file, he cannot write it, and I get a permission denied error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/monscript.py", line 30, in <module>
    mirror(parentDirectory + '/electhon1',parentDirectory + '/electhon2')
  File "/app/monscript.py", line 24, in mirror
    copyHtml(origin_path,copy_path)
  File "/app/monscript.py", line 9, in copyHtml
    with open(copy_path,'w') as fw:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/app/electhon2/index-2.html
```

Could anyone help me with this matter ?

Comment: I precise that I have tried to add lines like RUN chmod 777 /target_on_container -R, which gives to everyone the rights to write on all files and repositories inside /target_on_container, but then any newly created files can't be accessed by nonroot

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  What are the actual permission errors, and what does the code that looks like that''s writing the file?  What are the permissions on the host directory?  Are you in an environment where host user IDs might be remapped inside the container (on a MacOS host; with user remapping enabled)?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment ! I edited my question to include a code as small as possible to isolate the problem. As you can see, it occurs when nonroot tries to write files on the host. For information, the repository doesn't exist on the host before the execution of the dockerfile, but is created after despite the error, and all the permission are granted to root (the root of the host)

Comment: If you `ls -ln stored_files` on the host, what is the _numeric_ user ID that owns that host directory?  That needs to match the _numeric_ user ID of the non-root user in the container.  (Consider a `docker run -u 1001` option or similar, rather than trying to set it in the Dockerfile.)